# Pass value from VF to extension

Tags: controller-extension

I am facing a behaviour I cannot understand. The feature works fine with custom controller, but not with standard controller extension.

Essentially I have inputHidden field which value I update with JS. It is bound to a getter/setter in a controller.

Works great in controller, but in extension (two completely different pages btw) it's not getting the value.

To add to the space oddity, there is one picklist that runs some action function bounded to void method in extension, after which my variable does get assigned!

My suspicion is that I am missing some knowledge about how extensions work. Anyone got ideas what I am doing wrong?

Page where extension is used:

```
     <apex:form>
        <apex:actionFunction name="setSelectedRI" action="{!doNothing}" rerender="baz" oncomplete="showFields();" >
        </apex:actionFunction>
        <apex:pageBlock title="RI" id="qux">
            <apex:inputHidden value="{!isInConsole}" id="isInConsole" />
            <apex:includeScript value="/support/console/37.0/integration.js"/>
            <script type="text/javascript">
              document.querySelector('input[id$="isInConsole"]').value = sforce.console.isInConsole();
            </script>
            <apex:pageMessages id="pageMessages"/>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons id="buttons">
                <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel" status="closer" rerender="buttons" id="cancelButton" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="quxs">
                <apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(strMessage != null || strMessage != '', True, False)}" style=""><b><font color="red">{!strMessage}</font></b></apex:outputText>                
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="foo">
                    <apex:outputLabel value="RI Status" />
                    <apex:selectList value="{!selectedRI}" id="selectedRI" multiselect="false" size="1" disabled="{!bHasOpenComplaint }" onchange="setSelectedRI(this.options[this.selectedIndex])"> 
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!RIList}"/>
                    </apex:selectList>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
```

Page where controller is used:

```
<apex:inputHidden value="{!isInConsole}" id="isInConsole" />
            <apex:includeScript value="/support/console/37.0/integration.js"/>
            <script type="text/javascript">
              document.querySelector('input[id$="isInConsole"]').value = sforce.console.isInConsole();
            </script>

            <apex:pageBlockButtons rendered="{!IF(active || activeHistory,true,false)}">
                <apex:commandButton action="{!savePrompts}" value="Save"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
```

**Edit**: It seems there is some requirement that sections must be [rerendered in order the values to be passed.](http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.co.nz/2011/07/passing-parameters-to-apex-method-from.html) Investigating.

Comment: I think you need to add a more complete example.

Comment: Would some part of controller help?

Comment: Found the problem: cancel() is considered standard method so VF doesn't evaluate any parameters. Renamed method and it worked fine. Shame on me.